# How to sort User and Role in core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to display a list of Roles with users in my view.

This is my current output:

Role | Email

A | aaa@example.com

B | bbb@example.com

B | abc@example.com

C | baa@example.com

But I want it to be like this:

Role | Email

A | aaa@example.com

B | abc@example.com <--order by Role, then Email

B | bbb@example.com

C | baa@example.com

Any idea how to order the child in collection?

SettingController.cs

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

    public SettingController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var usersWithRole = _roleManager.Roles.Include(r => r.UserRoles).ThenInclude(u => u.User).OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList();

        return View(usersWithRole);
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    ViewData["Name"] = "Index";
    int count = 1;
}
<table class="table table-striped bg-white">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var role in Model)
        {
            var result = role.UserRoles;
            @foreach(var userRole in result)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@count</td>
                    <td>@role.Name</td>
                    <td>@userRole.User</td>
                </tr>
                count++;
            }   
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ApplicationRole.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUserRole.cs

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find a way to get the result that I wanted.

I create entities for the tables and access it via linq instead of using Identity's UserManager and RoleManager.

Then, I bind the result to ViewModel and display it in my view.

Controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {

        //var usersWithRole = _roleManager.Roles.Include(r => r.UserRoles).ThenInclude(u => u.User).OrderBy(r => r.Id).ToList();

        var roleAndUsers = (from r in _context.Role
                     join ur in _context.UserRole
                     on r.Id equals ur.RoleId
                     join u in _context.User
                     on ur.UserId equals u.Id
                     orderby r.Name, u.Email
                     select new UserAndRoleViewModel { Name = r.Name, Email = u.Email, Id = u.Id }).ToList();

        return View(roleAndUsers);
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class UserAndRoleViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    int count=1;
}
<table class="table table-striped bg-white">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var role in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@count</td>
                <td>@role.Name</td>
                <td>@role.Email</td>
            </tr>
            count++;
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ApplicationDbContext

```
    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> Role { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> User { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ThenBy()` method for the second sort column like below to have `order by Name, Email asc`

```
 var usersWithRole = _roleManager.Roles.Include(r => r.UserRoles)
                      .ThenInclude(u => u.User)
                      .OrderBy(r => r.Name)
                      .ThenBy(l => l.Email)
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, I tried your suggestion but it returns error.

'ApplicationRole' does not contain a definition for 'Email' and no accessible extension method 'Email' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationRole' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JustinOng Then post `ApplicationRole` entity schema

Comment: I have added my ApplicationDbContext.cs